# Como seleccionar un radiobutton con jquery despues de realizar una consulta a mi base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Hola amigos no tengo idea de como seleccionar un radiobutton a partir de una consulta en jQuery, es decir realice, una consulta a mi base de datos traje algunos campos los cuales ya los pude colocar es sus respectivos textbox, pero no tengo idea de como puedo hacerlo con un radiobutton, si no me explique lo suficiente les dejo mi codigo para que puedan entenderme.

asi es como tengo mis radiobuttons en mi html.

```
<div id="check" style="display: none" class="respuesta">

<label for="Si"><font size="4">Si:</font></label>
<input type= "radio" name="respuesta2" id="respuesta2" value= "si">
 <label for="No"><font size="4">No:</font></label>
<input type= "radio" name="respuesta2" id="respuesta3" value= "no">

 </div>
```

y con JQuery asi es la manera en que quiero seleccionar pero no funciona

```
success: function(result){    
    var preguntas  = result.split('|||')[0];             
    var tipo = result.split('|||')[1]; 
    var respuesta = result.split('|||')[2];
    var respuesta1 = result.split('|||')[3]; 
    var respuesta2 = result.split('|||')[4]; 

                        //llamamos la etiqueta igual por el id
                        $("#pregunta").text(preguntas);
                        $("#preg").val(preguntas);
                        $("#" + tipo).show();
                        $("#respuestas").val(respuesta);
                        $("#respuesta1").val(respuesta1);


 if (respuesta2=="no"){// esta es la parte que no se si este haciendo bien
    $("input[type='radio'][name='respuesta2'][value='no']").attr('checked',true);
}else{
    $("input[type='radio'][name='respuesta2'][value='si']").attr('checked',true);
}



                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de `attr` utiliza `prop` asi:

```js
    
  var respuesta2 = "no"; 

 if (respuesta2=="no"){// esta es la parte que no se si este haciendo bien
    $("input[type='radio'][name='respuesta2'][value='no']").prop('checked',true);
}else{
    $("input[type='radio'][name='respuesta2'][value='si']").prop('checked',true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="check" class="respuesta">

<label for="Si"><font size="4">Si:</font></label>
<input type= "radio" name="respuesta2" id="respuesta2" value= "si">
 <label for="No"><font size="4">No:</font></label>
<input type= "radio" name="respuesta2" id="respuesta3" value= "no">

 </div>
```

Comment: ya lo hice ahora el problema es que solo me selecciona el radiobutton SI y en mi tabla de base de datos tengo campos con la seleccion NO

Comment: Eso quiere decir que tu variable `respuesta2` no tiene el valor correcto.

Comment: Intenta asi: `if (respuesta2.trim()=="no"){`

Comment: eso era muchísimas gracias!!!, ya tenia todo el día y no podia encontrar el error